# How to use ETW from a C++ Windows client

Tags: c++, etw

I'm researching [Event Tracing for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/event-tracing-for-windows) (ETW) to allow a user-mode windows client to write out tracing information. The existing documentation is, to put it lightly, insanely incomplete. What would really help is a simple C++ example that writes out tracing messages using ETW. Does such an example exist? Is there other ETW documentation you might recommend?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To write a [**Provider**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363668(VS.85).aspx) for ETW, you have two options:

- write it as a manifest-based provider (preferred for Windows Vista or higher). Check out [an example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364162(VS.85).aspx).
- write it as a classic provider for legacy support. You can find [an example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364148(VS.85).aspx).

I suppose you want to use a manifest-based approach, as its better and can support up to eight sessions. The first step a manifest-based provider needs to do is to register the event using [`EventRegister()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363744(VS.85).aspx) and then write to it via the [`EventWrite()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363752(VS.85).aspx) or [`EventWriteString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363750(VS.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 8):

*[Programmers Guide to Eventing](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/7/7E7662CF-CBEA-470B-A97E-CE7CE0D98DC2/eventing-guide.docx)* (2010) from Microsoft is a good one to start with.

Comment: Can you provide a summary (this is currently a link-only answer)?